# How to change Laravel Auth::attempt method query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I need to change the default Laravel query from `Auth::attempt()`.

In the docs I saw two ways:

- Pass more parameters to the `Auth::attempt()` method;
- Create my own `User provider`.

The first solution not works for me, because I need to add a `OR` clause on the query (`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? OR phone=?`), and not an `AND` clause.
The second solution should be the correct one, but very complex, as I only need the `retrieveByCredentials` method.

Is there another way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's documented but you can do the following:

```
$givenField = '123456';

Auth::attempt([
  'email' => function ($query) use ($givenField) { 
     $query->where('email', $givenField)
       ->orWhere('phone', $givenField)->from('users')->select('email');
]);
```

This is a bit hacky. It usually allows you to query other tables but here it's the same one